# Webform in MVC app does not show in IIS7.5

Tags: model-view-controller, webforms, iis-7.5, reportviewer

I have a webform (using the ReportViewer) that is in an MVC application.  It is outside the Views folder in a root level folder called Reports.  The webform page works correctly when using VS2010 and the web server (Development Server, WebDev.WebServer, Cassini).  When using IIS7.5 with an integrated Application Pool (also tried Classic and set the ISAPI restrictions to allow), it does not work.  I have the modules..handlers item (Reserved-ReportViewerWebControl-axd) in web.config.

I am getting this page result: "The resource cannot be found." / Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for ...

I hope someone has a fix for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the file(s) under the content folder.  That should remove any route problems.